# Как удалить сессию в golang?

Tags: сессия, golang

Использую "github.com/gorilla/sessions" - http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions

Создаю сессию - всё нормально. А вот только как её удалить? Там вносится в список сессий, но нужно удалить и из списка сессий и саму сессию, чтоб не захламлять память.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался:

```
session.Options.MaxAge = 0 
session.Save(r, w)
```